# Why does Spring boot autoconfigure's feature overriding the profile mechanism?

Tags: spring-boot

This is the code where I created a H2 datasource. It should be available only when 'dev' profile is active.

```
@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public DataSource h2() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(H2).build();
}
```

But when I boot the application without any profile set, the spring boot initialize the H2 ignoring the profile annotation. Here is the output messages of spring boot at startup:

`No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`

`Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb ...`

Comment: The active profile should be respected. Can you share a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) of your problem?

Comment: H2 is initialized because it is on the classpath. Not because of your bean definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile isn't being ignored and it isn't your `DataSource` bean that's being created. It's Spring Boot's `DataSource` bean that's configured by `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. It's running because H2 is on the class path.

If you don't want a `DataSource` to be auto-configured (so that you only get one when the `dev` profile is active), then you should exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Andy, my requirement is to provide 2 datasources for the application, H2 and HSQL. My solution to control which of them will be load at startup is the profile mechanism. So, I set H2 to the dev profile and HSQL to stage profile. According to your answer, if H2 is on the classpath, does not matter if I set profile to each datasource bean, because DataSourceAutoConfiguration always will load the first datasource it founds at classpath. That's why I asked about the relation among autoconfigure and profile mechanism. I just update the github demo to exemplify that with an endpoint /dataSource.